# Is there a Proof assistant that is an esoteric programming language?

Tags: design

Is there a Proof assistant which also is an [esoteric programming language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language)? If so, then how many there are, approximately?

Comment: I think a cynic might argue that theorem provers form a proper subset of esoteric programming languages ;)

Comment: We do have checkers for CoC whose code fits on a postcard and stuff like that :)

Comment: I upvoted because I don't think this question needs to be downvoted, but I'm sorry to say that I close-voted since the community overwhelmingly didn't like it being open. 1-line questions in general tend to be poorly received, so some advice for the future would be to focus more on the quality of the question.

Answer (score 5):

- [Falso, by Estatis Inc.](https://inutile.club/estatis/falso/) is perhaps technically an esoteric programming language, fitting into the "designed [...] as a joke" category.
- I've occasionally thought about how to leverage C++ templates (which do sort-of support dependent types) to get `gcc` to check proofs for me.  This satisfies the "hard to program in" criterion.